# POST with checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

The following code is made of JQuery 1.3.
How can i get it to work with the latest version: 1.9.1
I also need it to remove the checked checkbox when the delete link is clicked.
I think I should use the remove() function for that.

The checkboxes is like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="prog" value="C">
```

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#submit_prog").click(
                function()
                {
                    var query_string = '';

                    $("input[@type='checkbox'][@name='prog']").each(
                        function()
                        {
                            if(this.checked)
                            {
                                query_string += "&prog[]=" + this.value;
                            }
                        });

                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "post_prog.php",
                            data: "id=1" + query_string,
                            success: 
                                function(t) 
                                {
                                    $("div#content").empty().append(t);
                                },
                            error:
                                function()
                                {
                                    $("div#content").append("An error occured during processing");
                                }
                         });    
                });
    });
```

EDIT:
Can I do this to remove the checkbox on delete:

```
function(event)
{
   if(this.checked)
    {
    query_string += "&prog[]=" + this.value;
    $(this).remove();
        }
}
```

Comment: The checkboxes is like this:
<input type="checkbox" name="prog" value="C">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line is supposed to read

```
$("input[@type='checkbox'][@name='prog']")
```

as

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='prog']")
```

Also a good idea to change the signature of the event handler

```
 $("#submit_prog").click(function () {
```

to

```
 $("#submit_prog").on('click', function () {
```

Comment: Okay, what about the remove function?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can select only `:checked` checkboxes to eliminate the need for your `if` statement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_prog").on("click", function () {
         var query_string = '';

         $("input[type='checkbox'][name='prog']:checked").each(function () {
             query_string += "&prog[]=" + this.value;
             $(this).remove();
         });

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "post_prog.php",
             data: "id=1" + query_string,
             success: function(t) {
                 $("div#content").empty().append(t);
             },
             error: function() {
                 $("div#content").append("An error occured during processing");
             }
         });    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Remove '@' from the selectors

2- Use jQuery.on('click', function(){} instead of jQuery.click() function

3- Use the jQuery promise functions:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post_prog.php",
    data: "id=1" + query_string
})
    .done(function (t) {
    $("div#content").empty().append(t);
})
    .error(function () {
    $("div#content").append("An error occured during processing");
});
```

Comment: Okay, and the checkbox remove function?

Comment: It should work find when you remove '@'.

or you can add the :checked pseudo selector:

<pre>
 $("input[type='checkbox'][name='prog']:checked").each(function () {
             query_string += "&prog[]=" + this.value;
             $(this).remove();
         });
</pre>